# Listing the employees of every department

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm working with two tables, dept (department) and emp (employees).

This is the description for dept.

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
DEPTNO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
DNAME                                              VARCHAR2(14)
LOC                                                VARCHAR2(13)
```

This is the description for emp.

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 EMPNO                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 ENAME                                              VARCHAR2(10)
 JOB                                                VARCHAR2(9)
 MGR                                                NUMBER(4)
 HIREDATE                                           DATE
 SAL                                                NUMBER(7,2)
 COMM                                               NUMBER(7,2)
 DEPTNO                                             NUMBER(2)
```

Now, I want to list all the employees in every department and produce the output like this:

```
  DEPTNO DNAME              LOC           
---------- -------------- ------------- 
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK      
 EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
  7782 CLARK
  7839 KING
  7934 MILLER


    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS        
 EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
  7369 SMITH
  7566 JONES
  7788 SCOTT
  7876 ADAMS
  7902 FORD


    30 SALES          CHICAGO       
 EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
  7499 ALLEN
  7521 WARD
  7654 MARTIN
  7698 BLAKE
  7844 TURNER
  7900 JAMES

    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON 
    50 MAINTENANCE    DALLAS
```

The last two departments have no employees working in them. So far, I've come up with this query:

```
 select d.deptno, d.dname, d.loc, e.empno, e.ename
 from dept d left join emp e on (d.deptno = e.deptno)
 order by d.deptno;
```

And this give me the following result:

```
DEPTNO DNAME          LOC                EMPNO ENAME
---------- -------------- ------------- ---------- ----------
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK            7782 CLARK
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK            7839 KING
    10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK            7934 MILLER
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS              7566 JONES
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS              7788 SCOTT
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS              7369 SMITH
    20 RESEARCH       DALLAS              7876 ADAMS
    30 SALES          CHICAGO             7499 ALLEN
    30 SALES          CHICAGO             7900 JAMES
    30 SALES          CHICAGO             7844 TURNER
    30 SALES          CHICAGO             7521 WARD
    30 SALES          CHICAGO             7698 BLAKE
    30 SALES          CHICAGO             7654 MARTIN
    40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON
    50 MAINTENANCE    DALLAS
```

As you can see, it lists the department number and name with every record whereas I want it to show only once. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: This is something which is probably best handled in your presentation layer rather than in Oracle.  Databases generate data, but they are not designed for complex formatting.

Comment: When you execute a SELECT (that returns data of course), you get a **TABLE** where all records have the same structure. You can get what you want via some coding (stored procedure) that uses cursors and responds with a textual result (not a table). As @TimBiegeleisen suggests, do the hiding within the your client application.

Comment: This is actually an assignment in a beginner level Database course so I don't have any application. I have to do this purely using SQL.

Comment: Can you use a reporting tool in oracle instead?

Comment: It has to be in SQL only.

Comment: You should probably ask your Trainer to specify clearly what he/she wants from you. What particular feature of "pure SQL" you are expected to use and why is it important for you to know it etc. As others have already noted, fundamentally SQL has to do with how you extract / modify data in the db and not how you present it in user-friendly formats, for which GUI based languages are used. It could still be done using PL/SQL, not sure if that is what you(or your Trainer) wants.

Comment: Are you using SQL*Plus? Is this question about beautifying the output? Are you absolutely sure that the output should have multiple lines with column names?

Comment: Yet another homework question; I tried to answer it, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458314/sql-query-to-display-a-parent-tables-record-followed-by-all-its-child-tables-r/49461586#49461586 but - it doesn't quite look as the desired output. Why? Because I don't know how to do it. I'd like to see if someone manages to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This is the closest possible result that I could work out.

```
select case when rn = 1 then deptno else null end deptno,
       case when rn = 1 then dname else null end dname,
       case when rn = 1 then loc else null end loc,
       empno, 
       ename 
  from (select d.deptno, 
               d.dname, 
               d.loc, 
               e.empno, 
               e.ename,
               row_number() over(partition by d.deptno order by e.empno) rn,
               row_number() over(order by d.deptno, e.empno) fullrn
          from dept d 
               left join 
               emp e 
            on (d.deptno = e.deptno))
order by fullrn;
```

Output:

```
DEPTNO  DNAME       LOC        EMPNO    ENAME
10      ACCOUNTING  NEW YORK   7782     CLARK
 -       -           -         7839     KING
 -       -           -         7934     MILLER
20      RESEARCH    DALLAS     7369     SMITH
 -       -           -         7566     JONES
 -       -           -         7788     SCOTT
 -       -           -         7876     ADAMS
 -       -           -         7902     FORD
30      SALES       CHICAGO    7499     ALLEN
 -       -           -         7521     WARD
 -       -           -         7654     MARTIN
 -       -           -         7698     BLAKE
 -       -           -         7844     TURNER
 -       -           -         7900     JAMES
40      OPERATIONS  BOSTON      -        - 
50      MAINTENANCE DALLAS      -        -
```